# Can bootstrap dropdown slide out from left to right instead of top to bottom?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I understand that this can be done on submenus but is there a way or workaround to open the main dropdown to the right?

Ideal result:
[image]

Comment: Ouch! -2 and no explanation. Angry community for new learners.

Comment: Not that new - 30 rep. It's not a bad question, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the position of the dropdowns: https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/196p47u8/

```
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(60%);
}
```